# 2 Separate folders for a single Game

Tags: networking, hard-drive, network-shares, shared-folders

I would like to have a solution where I can place Software or Games on a shared network drive and not have configuration files generated on it aswell. I don't want one user opening the Program and it generating config files for them and then another User opening it and having to use the previous User's config files.

My Hypothetical solution is to have the Bear Minimum files for the Program on the Shared Drive but then have the other files generated in the User's Appdata folder. In a way, the folders will be merged but if the computer cannot find a config file on the network drive it instead creates the files locally while still reading necessary program files from the network drive.

I looked into using Junctions but it doesn't seem possible to do that. If you can wrap your head around this idea could I please have so help with this?

Comment: Whether an application saves configuration data to the same directory is installed is an application-specific behavior. Unless we know what applications are in view here, this question is too broad.